# Off diagonal elements of correlation and data rank.

Tags: correlation

I have a data matrix M, and it's correlation matrix $M^TM$.  If the correlation matrix ($M^TM$) has higher magnitude elements off the diagonal, does this imply anything about the rank of the data matrix $M$?

Comment: By definition, a correlation matrix has $1$ on the diagonal.  No off-diagonal entry can every exceed that in size.  This suggests you are actually working with non-standardized data and that $M^\prime M$ is really the *sum of squares and products* matrix, not the correlation matrix.  Please clarify this point.

Comment: $M^TM/n$ is a correlation matrix *only* in very special cases. Eg. if all the variables are mean zero, then $M^TM/n$ is a covariance matrix (since $E[(x - E[x])(x - E[x])'] = E[xx'] - E[x]E[x]'$), and if all the variables also are standard deviation 1, then correlation matrix is the same as the covariance matrix.

Comment: I think higher magnitude for the correlation matrix means closer to 1, and higher magnitude for the sum of squares and products matrix just means away from 0.  So my question is asking for either case, what the higher magnitudes tell about the data (especially about the rank of the data matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, I'm going to assume that your data matrix $M \in \mathbb R^{n \times p}$ is normalized so that $M^T M$ actually is the correlation matrix. whuber pointed out that the diagonal of $M^T M$ is necessarily 1 and all other elements are at most 1 in absolute value, so it cannot be that off-diagonal elements are larger than the diagonal ones. I'm instead going to answer what happens when there are off-diagonal elements that are large in absolute value.

Note that $M^T M$ is always positive semi-definite, and is positive definite if and only if $M$ is full rank. This means that we can answer your question about the rank of $M$ by looking at how "far" from being positive definite $M^T M$ is. This exactly answers the question of how far from full-rank $M$ is. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/349738/prove-rank-ata-rank-a-for-any-a-m-times-n) for a proof that $\text{rank} \ M^T M = \text{rank} \ M$.

If two columns of $M$ are perfectly correlated then we'll have an off-diagonal 1 in $M^T M$ (well, 2 1's by symmetry) and $M$ has rank of at most $p-1$ now (assuming $p < n$), because two columns are collinear. So we can relate the number of exact 1's and -1's in $M^T M$ to the number of collinear pairs of columns, but this doesn't tell us about larger sets of columns of $M$ that are collinear. We could easily have three columns of $M$ being perfectly collinear without any pair being collinear. To assess that we should look at the eigenvalues of $M^T M$.

By the spectral theorem we have $M^T M = Q \Lambda Q^T$ where $Q$ is an orthonormal matrix of eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, ordered from largest to smallest. $M^T M$ is PD iff all $\lambda_i > 0$; by $M^T M$ being PSD we know all $\lambda_i \geq 0$. This means that the rank of $M$ is equal to the number of non-zero eigenvalues $M^T M$ has. What's nice about this is that looking for 1's and -1's in $M^T M$ will tell us if pairs of columns are collinear, but looking at the eigenvalues will tell us if any arbitrary combinations of columns are collinear and that includes the pairs that the correlations would detect.

So, in a nutshell, you can look at the off-diagonal elements of $M^TM$ to learn about the rank of $M$, but its eigenvalues will be far more informative.

As a final comment, if you actually compute the eigenvalues of some observed matrix $M$, you likely won't find any eigenvalues exactly equal to 0 due to numerical rounding. Generally though it's pretty obvious which ones should be exactly 0. If you use `R` there's a function `zapsmall` which is often used for this.

Comment: +1 Nice, clear explanation.  I was thinking it should be possible to go a little further by noting that an off-diagonal value of $\rho$ in the correlation matrix guarantees an eigenvalue at least equal to $1+|\rho|$ and another eigenvalue less than $1$.  I suspect stronger statements could be made along these lines and would be interested to learn what information you might be able to share about this.

Comment: @whuber That is a result of the Hirschhorn circle theorem, right?

Comment: @General I don't see how it is, but it can be deduced with a similar-looking argument.  WLG, assume $\rho$ is the correlation of the first two columns of $M$. Let $x=(\sqrt{2}, \pm\sqrt{2}, 0, \ldots, 0)$ be a unit vector and compute $xM^\prime Mx^\prime = (1\pm\rho)x$. Since the largest eigenvalue exceeds whatever multiplier might appear, it is immediate that it is no less than $1+|\rho|$. Because the product of eigenvalues is the determinant, which cannot exceed $1$ for a correlation matrix, there must also be an eigenvalue not exceeding $(1+|\rho|)^{-1/(n-1)}\lt 1$.

Comment: @whuber I don't know of any such statements off the top of my head but I'd also be interested in seeing them. I'll try to look into it a bit more. Nice $1+\vert \rho \vert$ proof, too